# image thumbnail with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload

I am using angular-file-upload plugin for file upload. I am adding some more features to it I want to show the image thumbnail or just a thumbnail of file uploaded. Also I am adding the name and description of the file. I am done with the name and description part but unable to show the preview of the file as soon as it is browsed. How can I do that?

Thanks.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id="ng-app" ng-app="app"> <!-- id="ng-app" IE<8 -->

    <head>
        <title>Simple example</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

        <!-- Fix for old browsers -->
        <script src="http://nervgh.github.io/js/es5-shim.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://nervgh.github.io/js/es5-sham.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../console-sham.js"></script>

        <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <!--<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>-->
        <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../../angular-file-upload.js"></script>
        <script src="controllers.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            .my-drop-zone { border: dotted 3px lightgray; }
            .nv-file-over { border: dotted 3px red; } /* Default class applied to drop zones on over */
            .another-file-over-class { border: dotted 3px green; }

            html, body { height: 100%; }
            .upload-button {
    padding: 4px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
        </style>
<script>
        
        $(document).ready(function() {

    
    var readURL = function(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('.profile-pic').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }
    
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
    

    $(".file-upload").on('change', function(){
        readURL(this);
    });
    
    $(".upload-button").on('click', function() {
       $(".file-upload").click();
    });
});
        </script>
    </head>

    <!-- 1. nv-file-drop="" uploader="{Object}" options="{Object}" filters="{String}" -->
    <body ng-controller="AppController" nv-file-drop="" uploader="uploader" filters="queueLimit, customFilter">

        <div class="container">

    

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-3">

                    <h3>Select files</h3>

                  

                    <!-- Example: nv-file-select="" uploader="{Object}" options="{Object}" filters="{String}" -->
                    Multiple
                    <input type="file" nv-file-select="" accept="image/*" uploader="uploader" multiple  /><br/>

                    Single
                    <div class="upload-button">Upload Image</div>
                    <input type="file" class="file-upload" nv-file-select="" accept="image/*" uploader="uploader"  />
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-9" style="margin-bottom: 40px">

                    <h3>Upload queue</h3>
                    <p>Queue length: {{ uploader.queue.length }}</p>

                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th width="50%">Name</th>
                                <th ng-show="uploader.isHTML5">Size</th>
                                <th ng-show="uploader.isHTML5">Progress</th>
                                <th>Status</th>
                                <th>Actions</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="item in uploader.queue">
                         
                                <td>
                                   <img class="profile-pic" src="http://cdn.cutestpaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/l-Wittle-puppy-yawning.jpg" style="width:30px"/>  
                                    <strong>{{ item.file.name }}</strong></td>
                                <td ng-show="uploader.isHTML5" nowrap>{{ item.file.size/1024/1024|number:2 }} MB</td>
                                <td ng-show="uploader.isHTML5">
                                    <div class="progress" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                                        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" ng-style="{ 'width': item.progress + '%' }"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-center">
                                    <span ng-show="item.isSuccess"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>
                                    <span ng-show="item.isCancel"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i></span>
                                    <span ng-show="item.isError"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></span>
                                </td>
                                <td nowrap>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" ng-click="item.upload()" ng-disabled="item.isReady || item.isUploading || item.isSuccess">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> Upload
                                    </button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" ng-click="item.cancel()" ng-disabled="!item.isUploading">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></span> Cancel
                                    </button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" ng-click="item.remove()">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Remove
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                    <div>
                        <div>
                            Queue progress:
                            <div class="progress" style="">
                                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" ng-style="{ 'width': uploader.progress + '%' }"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-s" ng-click="uploader.uploadAll()" ng-disabled="!uploader.getNotUploadedItems().length">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> Upload all
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-s" ng-click="uploader.cancelAll()" ng-disabled="!uploader.isUploading">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></span> Cancel all
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-s" ng-click="uploader.clearQueue()" ng-disabled="!uploader.queue.length">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Remove all
                        </button>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

I have used jquery in this.

Comment: Can you share the image src generated?

Comment: Above is my html file only. I am using jquery but I want to use angular and also change the thumbnail with the image selected.